# How to generate a list of all (x, y, pixel value) tuples from a 2D image matrix with numpy?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scipy

Using python and probably numpy, how can I generate a list of all coordinates with a ( x, y, pixelValue(x,y) ) format? I can achieve this with for loops using the following:

```
img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)

data = []

for x in range(img.shape[1]):
    for y in range(img.shape[0]):
        data.append((x, y, data[x, y]))
```

but doing so takes a reeeeaally long time when my image contains ~4 million pixels. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  What problem are you trying to solve?```data``` is a (1-d) Python ```list``` : data[x,y]``` doesn't make sense.  Why don't you just access ```img``` directly?

Comment: Seems very close to this one : http://stackoverflow.com/q/38073791/3293881

Comment: Shoot it is very close to that. I'm a stack overflow rookie. I'm subtracting two images and then fitting a 3D curve to the result using scipy.optimize() but to do that I need to input a list of the coordinates. There's probably an easier way to do the whole process but I was attempting this first.

Comment: Also, thanks for the link! @Divakar

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.ndenumerate` will create a generator in no time. You can then convert it to a list if you really need (???) to.

```
>>> np.ndenumerate(np.eye(2))
<numpy.lib.index_tricks.ndenumerate at 0x20d485f8>

>>>for elem in np.ndenumerate(np.eye(2)):
...    print elem
...
((0L, 0L), 1.0)
((0L, 1L), 0.0)
((1L, 0L), 0.0)
((1L, 1L), 1.0)

>>>list(np.ndenumerate(np.eye(2)))
[((0L, 0L), 1.0), ((0L, 1L), 0.0), ((1L, 0L), 0.0), ((1L, 1L), 1.0)]
```